# Convert '{key1=value1, key2=value2}' format into an object

Tags: javascript

I have some strings having a format like this:

```
'{key1=value1, key2=value2}'
```

What's the best way to convert a string with this format into a JavaScript object?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's valid JSON you can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: @Sjoerd It should be ":" instead of "=" to be JSON...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost JSON you could parse:

```
JSON.parse('{key1=value1, key2=value2}'.replace(/=/g,":"))
```

**EDIT** With keys as strings (thx @MattGreer):

```
JSON.parse('{key1=value1, key2=value2}'.replace(/(\w+)=/g, '"$1":'))
```

**EDIT** With values as strings (thx @ajsie):

```
JSON.parse('{key1=value1, key2=value2}'.replace(/(\w+)=(\w+)/g, '"$1":"$2"'))
```

Comment: for it to be valid JSON, the keys must be strings.

Comment: Hm this gave me syntax error on the Chrome console: SyntaxError: Unexpected token v

Comment: Oh you forgot to put the values in quotes to. Here is an upgraded one: '{key1=value1, key2=value2}'.replace(/(\W)(\w+)=(\w+)/g, '$1"$2":"$3"')

Answer (score 1):

This could work. Not tested though.

```
var data = '{key1=value1, key2=value2}',
    values = data.match(/\w+=\w+/g),
    newObject = {},
    i, value;

for (i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
  value = values[i].split('=');
  newObject[value[0]] = value[1] ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In that format nothing built in will help you. That's not quite a valid object literal, so `eval` will fail (eval should be avoided anyway), and it's not quite a JSON string, so `JSON.parse` will fail too. Can you massage the format? If you could get it to be `{"key1": value1, "key2": value2 }`, then both of the things I mentioned would work out of the box. `JSON.parse` in particular would be good:

```
var resultingObject = JSON.parse('{"key1": value1, "key2": value2 }')
```

It will (probably) be easier to massage the data into a valid JSON format than try and write your own parser. But if you have no choice on the format, a parser is probably your only option.

In desperation, a crude function to convert the format to JSON through brute force (replace all '=' with ':', wrap the keys in quotes, probably via a regex) would work, but it'd be brittle.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are numbers, not strings, and the info came from a trusted source, then you could simply `eval` the string.

If the values can contain strings then you'll need to parse it.

Added: oops, I forgot that the key/value separator is a colon, not an equals. @sinsedrix solution is good, except that you need to eval it since it still isn't valid JSON. (JSON requires that the keys be strings, not bare-words.)